# Difference between Graph Transform Tool and scripts in python/tools?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to deploy trained models for inference and need to convert `tf.Variable` into `tf.constant`, and strip any unused graph nodes.

What's the difference between these two toolsets? They look like they serve the same purpose. Which one should I rely on?

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/python/tools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Graph Transform Tool is a more modern replacement for the older Python scripts.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, but to make matters even more confusing there's also [a third implementation in core with a seemingly very similar purpose](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/graph_util). It would be nice to just have a really high-level `tf.compile(graph, input_nodes, output_nodes)` that spits out a binary for deployment (after doing constant folding, node stripping, LLVM generation with XLA, etc. behind-the-scenes).